# Telegram bot updates to python dict conversion

Tags: python, json, dictionary, telegram, telegram-bot

I am trying to create a Telegram bot from scratch using python. I've done all the initial steps and got the bot token, and now what I want to do is, for easy manipulation of the data it sends me (Like getting the `first_name` of the person from `getupdates` method) I want the data neatly arranged into a python dictionary.

When I try `/getme`, I get this:
`b'{"ok":true,"result":{"id":999999999,"first_name":"telebotsrock","username":"sample_bot"}}'`
Since the `b'` at the beginning and `'` at the end causes an error when I do `json.loads(data)` (Where data is the thing given above converted to a string).

So I do `data[2:-1]` to remove the `b'` and `'` and `json.loads()` works just fine, but when I change the `/getme` to `/getupdates`, a bunch of new errors pop up.

All in all, it's a mess. Can someone give me a clean way to get data from the bot and sort it into a python dictionary? Please do not tell me to use a different language or just copy an existing bot framework.

My current code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json

token="999999999:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
site="https://api.telegram.org/bot"+token

content=str(urlopen(site+"/getme").read())
#content=str(urlopen(site+"/getupdates").read())
data=content[2:-1]
print(data)
info=json.loads(data)
print(info)
```

This code correctly coverts the output of `/getme` to a python dictionary, but gives errors when I try `/getupdates` instead.

Output of `/getupdates` before I slice it is:

`b'{"ok":true,"result":[{"update_id":66666666,\n"message":{"message_id":1,"from":{"id":777777777,"first_name":"Aswin","last_name":"G","username":"MatrixHunter"},"chat":{"id":777777777,"first_name":"Aswin","last_name":"G","username":"MatrixHunter","type":"private"},"date":1459932293,"text":"\\/start"}},{"update_id":88888888,\n"message":{"message_id":2,"from":{"id":777777777,"first_name":"Aswin","last_name":"G","username":"MatrixHunter"},"chat":{"id":777777777,"first_name":"Aswin","last_name":"G","username":"MatrixHunter","type":"private"},"date":1459932298,"text":"Oy"}}]}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you. You can use the `.decode('utf-8')` to get rid of the byte prefix.

```
token = "999999999:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
url="https://api.telegram.org/bot" +token + "/getme"

req = Request(url)
response = urlopen(req)
data = response.read().decode('utf-8')
json_data = json.loads(data)

print(str(data['ok'])) #should print True
```